# Sanitizing Form Data for MySQL table

Tags: mysql, forms

Will this do the trick if I am sanitizing code that is going from a form into a mysql table?  the data that should/will be entered will be school subjects and professor's first/last names...any other suggestions on how to do this?

```
/*
Sanitize() function removes any potential threat from the
data submitted. Prevents email injections or any other hacker attempts.
if $remove_nl is true, newline chracters are removed from the input.
*/
function Sanitize($str,$remove_nl=true)
{
    $str = $this->StripSlashes($str);

    if($remove_nl)
    {
        $injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
            '/(\r+)/i',
            '/(\t+)/i',
            '/(%0A+)/i',
            '/(%0D+)/i',
            '/(%08+)/i',
            '/(%09+)/i'
            );
        $str = preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
    }

    return $str;
}    
function StripSlashes($str)
{
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend PHP's [PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  You would do something like:

```
try
{
  $sql ='INSERT INTO whatever(a,b,c) VALUES(:a,:b:c);
  //or if you prefer...
  $sql ='INSERT INTO whatever(a,b,c) VALUES(?,?,?);
  $stmt = db::db()->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(array(123,234,345));
}
catch(PDOException $e){library::sql_error($e,$sql);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for taking the time to help.  I went with the preg_replace function which limits characters to only what i want people to use: `preg_replace("~" . "[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\ ]" . "~iU", "", $string)`.  I also used `mysql_real_escape_string` so I'm doing two levels of filtering before sending on to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) which escapes all potential characters that can cause issues? Besides being built in, it cals MySQL's own `mysql_real_escape_string` so you know you'll always be up to date on what needs to be escaped for your installed database.

Comment: Will do.  I had done some research on the issue but wasn't sure given the context(meaning the data I was trying to filter) if that was the proper way to do it.  Thanks a lot John!

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use PDO's bindValue method:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

This sorts out all your escaping.

For forms, you can also look at this:

http://semlabs.co.uk/docs/xfl/xfl-elements/sanitise

It's a set of PHP classes to handle forms with less hassle, though it will take a while to get your head round.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 function sanatize($value) {

            $value = preg_replace("~" . "[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]" . "~iU", "", $value);
            return $value;
    }
```